# Bullt-in GPU conflics with External GPU in Razer Chroma X

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, nvidia-geforce

My built-in GPU is Nvidia Quadro p1000. My external GPU is plugged into a Razer Chroma X and is ASUS GeForce RTX 2080 TI ROG Strix OC White - o11G.

When I plug in the Razer Chroma X via the thunderbolt, after a few minutes, everything works fine. When I switch off my PC, unplug the thunderbolt and switch it back on, the Quadro p1000 does not take over. Instead, I have to reinstall it every time I have to use it after plugging in the Razer Chroma X.

[image]

And here it is from the GeForce every time I restart the PC.

[image]

Is there a way I can re-use the Quadro p1000 without having to take the PC into the hell of reinstalling ?

After re-installing via GeForce, the graphics card is recognized and it works again.

[image]

Link for ASUS graphics card

https://www.asus.com/Graphics-Cards/ROG-STRIX-RTX2080TI-O11G-WHITE-GAMING/HelpDesk_Download/

And when the 2080TI is running

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue. The perpetrator was windows 10 drivers updates!

Step 1: DISABLE windows 10 driver update

start -> control panel -> devices and printers, under devices, find your PC icon, right click -> device installation settings. A pop up comes, select "No" for "do you want to automatically download manufacturers apps ad custom icons...."

Step 2: Uninstall all NVIDIA stuff

Download and install DDU from https://www.wagnardsoft.com/content/display-driver-uninstaller-ddu-v18024-released , and restart your PC in safe mode. Delete all NVIDIA stuff.

Step 3: Plug EGPU and Navigate to ASUS  website

Download NVIDA Driver from here, and it will be able to recognize both drivers and now you can run them side by side and switch between them without restarting your PC

https://www.asus.com/Graphics-Cards/ROG-STRIX-RTX2080TI-O11G-WHITE-GAMING/HelpDesk_Download/

[image]